# Manage long press bing maps

Tags: bing-maps

I have an app with Bing Map for **WinRT**. I need to manage the long time pressure. 
The behaviour should be this:

- if the user press in one point and move the finger the should be act as usual
- if the user press one point and stay in that point for at least 1 second I put a pushpin in that point.

How can I distinguish the normal press for moving the map from the "long press"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long press in Windows Store apps would fire a right click event. If you are using the .NET map control for Windows Store apps you can use the maps RightTapped event. If you are using the JavaScript version of Bing Maps you can use the click event. The event parameter will have a property called isSecondary set to true if it was a right click.

Comment: The solution partially works. The pin is added when the user release the pressure. It would be better if the pin was added after a lot of time also if the user continues to press. Is it possible? I have to use a timer?

Comment: A timer is an option. It would require a bit more work but would allow you to customize the amount of time required for a press to add a pin.